# How to change screen background color in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How to change screen background color in ActionScript 3.0 ? and how to navigate one screen to another screen in ActionScript3.0;
i have used a button in my project, when i click the button the present screen should be invisible and another screen should come

in the onclick method i called like this :

presentscree.visible = false;
nextscreen:NextScreen = new NextScree();
nextscreen.visible = true;

But no result; can any one help me on this ?

Comment: please check edited code, just realized i forgot one line for the change of background color!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the screen to the DisplayList otherwise it will not be visible at all.

```
var nextScreen : NextScreen = new NextScreen();
addChild(nextScreen);
```

You can change the background color of your screen like this:

```
graphics.beginFill(0xBBBBBB, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
graphics.endFill();
```

Or, if you want to change the SWF background color:

```
package
{

    [SWF( frameRate="30", backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF", width="800", height="600" )]
    public class MyDocumentClass extends Sprite
    {
        public function MyDocumentClass()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implemented the both things, but melt down, the color has not changed even navigation has not done.

Comment: The attribute thing is nice. Until now I always had to go to project properties in FlashDevelop. **Painting** the background color on a sprite is a bad solution I think. Can't move it afterwards. OpenGL has the ability to set clear color (background color). Flash should have that, too!

Answer (score 0):

Call this function anytime you want to change the backgroundColor

```
 private function backgroundColor( color:uint ):void
 {
   with( this.graphics )
   {
    clear();
    beginFill( color );
    drawRect( 0 , 0 , Capabilities.screenResolutionX, Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
    endFill();
   }
 }

  //example
  backgroundColor( 0x990000 );
```

To change the screen , you can add all your screens to an Array

```
private var screens:Array = [screen1 , screen2 , ...screenN];

//Assuming that all the screens have been added to the DisplayList 
private function selectScreen( index:int ):void
{
      //Ensure that the index is within bounds
      if( index >= screens.length )
         return;

      for( var i:int ; i < screens.length ; ++i )
      {
          if( i != index )
            screens[i].visible = false;
          else
            screens[i].visible = true;               
      }
 }

 //You could also add your screens with this 
 public function addScreen( screen:DisplayObject ):void
 {
       if( screens == null )
          screens = [];

      //add the screen to the Array
      screens.push( screen );

      //hide the screen
      screen.visible = false;

      //add the screen to the Display List
      addChild( screen ); 

  }
```